# mongodb deferred update while running the script

Tags: php, mongodb

I do not understand what is going on with my migration script. So a have a collection with 40+m records in it, and historically that collection did not have a strict model, so I'm working on adding default values for some optional fields, for example, if the document does not have `deleted_at` I'll add it with the `null` value.

Basically, I'm taking documents in batches by 300, checking if a document should be updated and if so updating it. All was fine, I was able to update 12M documents in 9 hours. But after that, something weird started to happen, first of all, it started to work much much slower, like 100k documents in an hour which is ~10x slower than was before. Also from the logs, I can see that script updating documents pretty fast (I have a bunch of log entries related to updated documents every second), but if I run the count query to get the number of modified documents, the amount is not increasing so often. For example, depending on logs in 10 seconds 400 rows were updated, but the number of modified documents did not increase when the count query runs. The number of the modified documents simply increases once per some period of time, for example, the number can be the same for 2-3 minutes, and then at some point, it increases on 4k rows.

So I do not understand why at some point mongo starts running updates with some delay, scheduling them or something, and why it starts to work slower?

The script is pretty big, but I'll try to share the simplified version, so you can see how I'm looping through documents:

```
class Migration {

    private Connection $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $collection)
    {
        $this->connection = $collection;
    }

   public function migrate(): void
   {
        $totalAmount = $this->connection->collection('collection')->count();
        $chunkSize = 300;

        $lastIdInBatch = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $totalAmount; $i += $chunkSize) {
            $aggregation = [];
            $aggregation[] = [
                '$sort' => ['_id' => 1],
            ];
            if ($lastIdInBatch !== null) {
                $aggregation[] = [
                    '$match' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            '$gt' => new ObjectId($lastIdInBatch),
                        ],
                    ],
               ];
            }
            $aggregation[] = [
                '$limit' => $chunkSize,
            ];
            $documents = $this->connection->collection('collection')->raw()->aggregate(
                $aggregation
            );
            
            $lastIdInBatch = $documents[array_key_last($documents)]['_id'];
            
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                // checks to see if we need to update the document
                // ....
                if (!empty($changes)) {
                   $updated = $this->connection
                      ->collection('collection')
                      ->where('_id', document['_id'])
                      ->update($changes);
                    if ($updated) {
                        Log::info('row udpated', ['product_id' => document['_id']]) // I see multiple of this logs each seconds, but no changes in database 
                    }
                }  
            }
          
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue self-healed after restart of kubernetes pod, so it seems like wasn't the issue with mongo